# Expand children of HStack equally?

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on converting a little calculator app from UIKit to SwiftUI, because managing the autolayout constraints is getting insane. To that end, I'm trying to make a keypad with various keys grouped in the view hierarchy like this: The top row is an `HStack`, the number keys are their own view, a `VStack` of `HStack`, and then two more `VStack` (see code below).

Unfortunately, the rows below the top row don’t expand to the full width. I’ve tried a wide variety of `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)`, but none seem to make that lower `HStack` expand fully horizontally.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode SwiftUI canvas showing stack issues]

I thought it might be because the number keys are their own view, but it does seem to get the heights consistent.

*Bonus points if you can tell me how to expand the "0" key to be twice the width of the "." key in that `HStack`.

```swift
struct
CalculatorView : View
{
    var
    body: some View
    {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0)
        {
            ResultsView()
            Keypad()
        }
    }
}

struct
ResultsView : View
{
    var
    body: some View
    {
        ZStack
        {
            Color.black
        }
    }
}

struct
Keypad : View
{
    var
    body: some View
    {
        ZStack
        {
//          Color.green
            VStack(spacing: 1.0)
            {
                HStack(spacing: 1.0)
                {
                    Key("AC", action: {})
                    Key("(", action: {})
                    Key(")", action: {})
                    Key("\(Fractional.fractionDash)", action: {})
                    Key("±", action: {})
                }
                HStack(spacing: 1.0)
                {
                    Numberpad()
                    VStack(spacing: 1.0)
                    {
                        Key("\(Fractional.fractionSlash)", action: {})
                        Key("mm", action: {})
                        Key("\"", action: {})
                        Key("DEL", action: {})
                    }
                    VStack(spacing: 1.0)
                    {
                        Key("÷", action: {}, backgroundColor: Color("OperatorButtonBackground"))
                        Key("×", action: {}, backgroundColor: Color("OperatorButtonBackground"))
                        Key("-", action: {}, backgroundColor: Color("OperatorButtonBackground"))
                        Key("+", action: {}, backgroundColor: Color("OperatorButtonBackground"))
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: false)
            }
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(Font.system(size: 30.0))
    }
}

struct
Numberpad : View
{
    var
    body: some View
    {
        ZStack
        {
            VStack(spacing: 1.0)
            {
                HStack(spacing: 1.0)
                {
                    Key("7", action: {})
                    Key("8", action: {})
                    Key("9", action: {})
                }
                HStack(spacing: 1.0)
                {
                    Key("4", action: {})
                    Key("5", action: {})
                    Key("6", action: {})
                }
                HStack(spacing: 1.0)
                {
                    Key("1", action: {})
                    Key("2", action: {})
                    Key("3", action: {})
                }
                HStack(spacing: 1.0)
                {
                    Key("0", action: {})
                    Key(".", action: {})
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}

struct
Key : View
{
    let     text                :   String
    let     action              :   () -> ()
    let     backgroundColor     :   Color?
    
    init(_ inText: String,
            action inAction: @escaping () -> (),
            backgroundColor inBC: Color? = nil)
    {
        self.text = inText
        self.action = inAction
        self.backgroundColor = inBC
    }
    
    var
    body: some View
    {
        ZStack
        {
            Button(action: {})
            {
                Text(self.text)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(self.backgroundColor ?? Color.gray)
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Approach

- `.fixedSize(horizontal:, vertical:)`
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/fixedsize(horizontal:vertical:)
- Causes the view to grow in the axis marked as `false` (false means it can grow)

## Solution:

```
Numberpad()
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```